# How do I create a form without refreshing the page at the same time the data goes into a mysql data base?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, forms

Ok, I know there have been a few questions posted on this but a lot of the information are dotted around and not necessarily connected in one form that I need for my site.

1. Basically I want to create the style/functionality of the twitter form on their home page.

Where inside the input fields are the labels, and when you click on the input the fields the labels don NOT disappear but fade into a different colour. Its only when you type, is when it disappears.

2. If they don't type and press submit I want the verification signs come up ( I know how to do this but it seems to be conflicting when I put the jQuery code in)
3. When all fields are inputted I would like the form to fade and represent a thank you message whilst
4. the data gets placed into a mysql ( specifically a MAMP/PHP My Admin) database.

Very similar to this form on hbuddy.com

Would massively appreciate if this was responded in a step by step format, simply because i am  at the beginning stages of learning pretty complex programming language.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a good exercise to learn the first steps of "a pretty complex programming language".

Answer (score 1):

you can try jquery ajax for form submission..

These links will help you for getting started..

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/04/submit-form-jquery-and-ajax.html

http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2008/11/04/use-jquery-to-submit-form/